# nz-table [nzFooter] not updating on tableData changes

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

Im trying to display number of displayed rows in my nz-table footer:

```
<nz-table 
    #filterTable 
    [nzData]="tableData" 
    nzShowPagination="false" 
    [nzPageSize]="tableData.length"
    [nzShowTotal]="tableData.length"
    [nzFooter]="('Display rows: '+ filterTable.data.length + '/' + totalData)"
    >
```

I have a search field to make it possible for the user to search items in the table - on changes in search the tableData is updated and rows re-rendered in the table is correct. Except for the footer, it still shows filterTable.data.length that was earlier rendered.

But if I render a tr within the tbody, it'll show correct amount of rows:

```
    <tr *ngIf="showFooter" class="table-footer">
        {{filterTable.data.length}}
    </tr> 

</tbody>
```

Trying to use a custom pipe, but the pipe isnt called right away, but "one change behind" as well.
Any one got any idea why the filterTable.data isnt updated in nz-table-element but in tbody-element?